# listening to on-select event of angularj ui select

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-ui-select

I am creating an custom attribute which will send angular ui select data to the server. However, in my custom directive I need to bind to `on-select` event to achieve this.

Here is my html code for the directive:

```
 <div class="component">
        <ui-select send-data ng-model="country.selected" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries | filter: $select.search">
                <span ng-bind-html="country.name | html"></span>
                <small ng-bind-html="country.code | html"></small>
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
    </div>
```

Notice that the directive is using an custom directive `send-data`.
And here is my directive:

```
var app = angular.module('app');
app.directive('sendData', [
        '$compile', '$timeout', '$http', function ($compile, $timeout, $http) {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {                         
                    el.on('on-select', function () {
                        console.log("changed");
                    });                 
                }
            };
        }
]);
```

The `console.log("changed");` statement is not firing in the above directive. 
why is this, have i got it wrong?

I am aware that I can bind to the `on-select` event from the controller. But I would like to achieve this in a custom attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, `on-select` is not an event (like click, keydown) so you can bind a listener, The way `ui-select` [implement it](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/src/uiSelectDirective.js#L47) they just bind a controller or parent level function.

So it is better to let `ui-select` handle the `on-select` method.

If you have any DOM manipulation in `on-select` then in your `sendData` directive you have to find the proper `li` element and set on `click` event.